# How to avoid qWarning of float values

Tags: c++, qt, qml, warnings

I have these following code to set a variable:

```
void TypeLogVisualization::setGain(double gain)
{
qWarning("Floating point comparison needs context sanity check");
if (qFuzzyCompare(m_gain, gain) || gain < 1.0 || gain > 2.1)
    return;

m_gain = gain;
setPath();
emit gainChanged(m_gain);
}
```

The variable gain is set in QML File, like the code bellow:

```
function gainMinus(){
    log.setGain(log.gain-=0.1)
}

function gainPlus(){
    log.setGain(log.gain+=0.1)
}
```

log is object of a classe who contains "setGain", gain is a QProperty. I really want know how to avoid that warning: **Floating point comparison needs context sanity check**

Comment: The line will execute for any call of setGain() so to remove the warning delete the line.

Comment: I thought there is a way to avoid that without remove the line

Comment: To me the warning looks like a work to todo comment that the developers accidentally left in the code after implementing the check.

Comment: @antuniooh "I thought there is a way to avoid that without remove the line" - the warning is *obviously* generated every time the function is called, unconditionally. How would you avoid it except by removing it or making it conditional on something?

Comment: @antuniooh If you want to avoid that warning in that place, only, you'll have to remove or comment out that line of code. If you want to turn off *all* `qWarning`'s see [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qWarning).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [logging categories](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html) ? They can be switched off from environment variables or runtime too

Comment: see it [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qWarning): _This function does nothing if QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT was defined during compilation_

Comment: Thanks everyone, i comment the line to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everyone said, the only way it's remove that lines